# Native Salesforce lead-to-client process to handle custom lead object

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I am a developer so sorry if I am asking an obvious question (not familiar with the business side in Salesforce).

We have a custom lead object with custom lead statuses (designed after what our client wants). From what I know, Salesforce has its own native business process to take a lead through different stages to an opportunity or sales.

I wanted to know if I can use this native Salesforce business process to handle our custom lead object with custom lead statuses.

Our clients lead to sales process is not much different from the default Salesforce process.  It's just that the stages are different. Each stage has a series of statuses that determine the next stage.

If these stages can be handled through native SFDC business process that would be great!

Hopefully my question was clear. I would appreciate any help or suggestion regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but based on the information you've provided, I'd highly recommend reverting back to the standard Lead object.  Perhaps a better question might be, how do you get the standard Lead object to do what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cant create custom object by using **Default** Web to lead( or web to case) implementation.

You can only create leads & cases by that feature.

If you are using any custom object as lead then you will have to use workarounds.

There are couple of options for you.

1) Using public site allow unauthenticated user to create custom lead record 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_overview.htm&language=en_US

2) Use default implementation of web to lead and write trigger on standard lead object to transfer standard lead data into your custom lead object. And may be delete the original lead by using schedule job.

Both of these are just workarounds and you should consider performance & security risks when using them.

Comment: Thanks. What if I customize the existing Lead object according to the client needs. Will that work?

Comment: Yes, standard lead will work for sure.

Comment: Ideally I need to find a way to implement the standard lead sales process going from initial stages to final stages...the values of the stages will be driven by another field called status which will reside on a custom lead object

Comment: This answer focuses on web-to-lead when the question focuses on lead conversion. I agree that customizing the existing lead is preferable to creating a new one.